# Using tidyverse to clean up rank-choice survey

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, survey, case-when

I have survey data in R that looks like this, where I've presented people with two groups of actions - High and Low - and asked them to rank each action. Each group contains unique actions, marked by the letter (6 actions in total).

```
 id   A_High   B_High   C_High   D_Low   E_Low    F_Low
001       5         2         1      6       4        3
002       6         4         3      5       2        1
003       3         1         6      2       4        5
004       6         5         2      1       3        4
```

I need a new df that looks like the one below, where each High action is assigned a new numeric rank (between 0 and 3) corresponding to the number of Low action items that were ranked **below** that High action.

For example, a person with `id` 001 ranked `A_High` at number 5, `B_High` at 2, and `C_High` at 1. `A_High`'s new rank would be 1 (since only 1 Low action, `D_Low` is ranked below `A_High`), `B_High`'s new rank would be 3 (since all 3 Low actions were ranked below B_High), and `C_High`'s new rank would be 3 (since all 3 Low actions were ranked below `C_High`).

```
 id   A_High_rank   B_High_rank   C_High_rank   
001             1             3             3                      
002             0             1             1           
003             2             3             0           
004             0             0             2
```

I have a sense that this can be done with if/else statements but suspect that there should be a far more efficient way of achieving this with tidyverse. In the real dataset, I have 1000+ rows and 12 actions (6 High and 6 Low). I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

Data:

```
"id   A_High   B_High   C_High   D_Low   E_Low    F_Low
001       5         2         1      6       4        3
002       6         4         3      5       2        1
003       3         1         6      2       4        5
004       6         5         2      1       3        4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `base R` option would be to loop over the 'High' columns, get the `rowSums` of the logical matrix created by checking if it less than the 'Low' column, and rename those output by appending `_rank` as suffix

```
out <- cbind(df1[1], sapply(df1[2:4],
    function(x) rowSums(x < df1[endsWith(names(df1), 'Low')])))
names(out)[-1] <- paste0(names(out)[-1], "_rank")
```

-output

```
out
#  id A_High_rank B_High_rank C_High_rank
#1  1           1           3           3
#2  2           0           1           1
#3  3           2           3           0
#4  4           0           0           2
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     transmute(id, across(ends_with('High'), 
        ~  rowSums(. <  select(df1, ends_with('Low'))), .names = '{.col}_rank'))
# id A_High_rank B_High_rank C_High_rank
#1  1           1           3           3
#2  2           0           1           1
#3  3           2           3           0
#4  4           0           0           2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:4, A_High = c(5L, 6L, 3L, 6L), B_High = c(2L, 
4L, 1L, 5L), C_High = c(1L, 3L, 6L, 2L), D_Low = c(6L, 5L, 2L, 
1L), E_Low = c(4L, 2L, 4L, 3L), F_Low = c(3L, 1L, 5L, 4L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

After much suffering, this is the `tidyverse` solution I came up with. This was fun!

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("_High"), names_to = "High Variables", values_to = "High") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("_Low"), names_to = "Low Variables", values_to = "Low") %>%
  filter(High-Low < 0) %>%
  group_by(`High Variables`, `id`) %>%
  summarise(Count = n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = `High Variables`, values_from = Count) %>%
  arrange(id)
```

Translation:
The first two line create two pairs of columns and leave `id` untouched. Each pair has two columns, one with the original column names, and the other with the values. Each pait of columns represents either `High` or `Low`.

Then, I filtered all the rows, keeping only those where `Low` was greater than `High`. Then I counted how many where left for each `id` and reversed back the format.

Now I just have to figure out how to turn those `NA`s into `0`s.

Here's the output:

```
> data %>%
+   pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("_High"), names_to = "High Variables", values_to = "High") %>%
+   pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("_Low"), names_to = "Low Variables", values_to = "Low") %>%
+   filter(High < Low) %>%
+   group_by(`High Variables`, `id`) %>%
+   summarise(Count = n()) %>%
+   pivot_wider(names_from = `High Variables`, values_from = Count) %>%
+   arrange(id)
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'High Variables' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id A_High B_High C_High
  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1     1      1      3      3
2     2     NA      1      1
3     3      2      3     NA
4     4     NA     NA      2
```

Comment: You're welcome, but I've got to confess @akrun 's answer is a lot more elegant... Honestly, I'm actually dissecting it myself...